# How to add matrix across the diagonal ("folding it in half") in R?

Tags: r, matrix

I need to add one half of my matrix to the other half across the diagonal. In my matrix (shown below), I need the "1" in 63,25 to be added to the "2" in 25,63, and so on for all values in the matrix.

Then I need a way to clear out half of the matrix, either above or below the diagonal.

I tried:

```
sum(diag(lakes_matrix))
```

but this did not work.

```r
      25 63 1567 40 50 60 70 80
25    0  2    0  0  0  0  0  0
63    1  0    0  0  0  0  0  0
1567  0  1    0  0  0  0  0  0
40    0  0    1  0  0  0  0  0
50    0  0    0  2  0  0  0  0
60    0  0    0  0  0  0  0  0
70    0  0    0  0  0  1  0  0
80    0  0    0  0  0  0  0  0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
m <- matrix(1:9, nrow = 3)
m
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    4    7
[2,]    2    5    8
[3,]    3    6    9
```

```
n <- m + t(m) # add transpose to original
n
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    2    6   10
[2,]    6   10   14
[3,]   10   14   18
```

```
n * upper.tri(n) # clear out the lower diagonal
```

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0    6   10
[2,]    0    0   14
[3,]    0    0    0
```

So you can make a function

```
my_func <- function(m) {
  # do some assertions: m is matrix, square and numeric etc
  (m + t(m)) * upper.tri(m)
}
```